# Get C# RDP Screen Byte Data

Tags: c#, streaming, rdp, mstsc

I need to get the screen byte data from an RDP client using the built in RDP/(Microsoft Terminal Services Control Type Library) libraries Microsoft provides for C#.  It would be great if I didnt have to use a windows form as well to host it which 'seems' to be required as shown in most of these c# rdp examples.

My basic use case here is that I need to transfer the screen byte data coming through the network rdp client(Microsoft Terminal Services Control Type Library) to display in a different medium that is not a C# windows form.

Is anyone aware of a method to achieve this?